# How to search a column within a mysql table using multiple keywords from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to make a search function for my database that refines the search with each additional keyword.

I don't want to limit it to a fixed number of keywords so I use a `foreach()` loop to extend the sql by another `AND column LIKE ?` for each keyword.

However the array-binder loop produces different results than using other methods that should do the exact same thing.

My table contains 1 column and 3 rows : "a b c", "b c", "1 2 3".

```
$Keywords = array("a","b","c"); //those search keywords should only apply to the first row
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ?";

foreach ($Keywords as $Keyword) {

    if ($count > 0) {       
        $sql = $sql . "AND column LIKE ?";
    }
    $count = $count + 1;
}
$query = $con->prepare($sql);

//loop to bind parameters
foreach ($Keywords as $n=>$Keyword) {
    $Keyword = "%".$Keyword."%";                                
    $query->bindParam($n+1,$Keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$query->execute;
```

This will return the rows `a b c` and `b c` although it should only return the row that contains all 3 strings: a , b and c.

If I don't use a loop to bind the parameters (which limits the number of keywords) it does what is is supposed to and only shows "a b c".

```
        $a = "%a%";
        $b = "%b%";
        $c = "%c%";
        $query->bindParam(1,$a,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(2,$b,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(3,$c,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

It also works If I just execute this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%a%' AND column LIKE '%b%' AND column LIKE '%c%'";
```

Comment: use mysql [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

The working examples use the `%` wildcard but your looped values don't.

Change

```
$Keywords = array("a","b","c");
```

to

```
$Keywords = array("%a%","%b%","%c%");
```

or another solution is to add the wildcards in the `bindParam` call

```
foreach ($Keywords as $n=>$Keyword) {                               
   $query->bindParam($n+1,"%$Keyword%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Another potential issue is that your constructed query doesn't have a space between `?` and `AND` i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ?AND column LIKE ?AND column LIKE ?
```

Although I'm not sure if a missing space after the `?` is illegal, I recommend padding your `AND` condition with spaces

```
$sql = $sql . " AND column LIKE ? ";
               ^                 ^
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does that explain why the OPs initial incorrectly matched the string 'b c', because they didn't have the `%`s in there? Off hand, I feel like the results should have been that nothing matched

Comment: @dwanderson after a closer look it appears that you're right, the results should have nothing matched

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the line that adds the "%" in my post, now I corrected it

Comment: I now tried all of your suggestions @Fuzzytree. All except,  the one that applies the wildcards in the bindParam call, of them producing the same result. I got this error when I added the wildcards like that: "Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference".